# Traefik/Portainer - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: traefik, portainer

I'm trying to setup Traefik and Portainer but seem to be hitting some issues. I think mainly around Traefik and setting up new containers.

Everything looks correct to me but I seem to be getting an error when I point to my subdomain

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

If I point to the IP address and Port, the Portainer dashboard is displayed, it just seems to be that when pointing to my sub-domain, there is some recursive redirection I'm assuming.

My docker compose looks like this:-

```
version: '3'

services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    container_name: portainer-new
   restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9000:9000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`MY_URL`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`MY_URL`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out my issue.

The above is correct and valid. I use CloudFlare for proxy/DNS etc... I had added my subdomain to my DNS settings, but my Proxy Status was Proxied rather than DNS ONLY. After setting DNS only the above worked.

Comment: This works thanks for posting. I seem to accidentally find another solution: leave Proxy Status as Proxied but turn SSL/TLS to Full mode.